# Query AWS RDS Through Alexa

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build a skill that will take a user input, run a query based on it and return some info from a database.

I have a database instance set up on AWS RDS and a skill that works off some javascript code on lambda but I'm struggling to link them.

I can query the db locally using a php file, but I wont be running  a server on the lambda side

Should i rebuild the entire skill in php?

Or add the db endpoint to my alexa skill? In that case how would i code the intents etc

I'm sure this must have been done before but I've struggled to find somewhere that explains it for a beginner.

**Update**

So i tried making an ajax call to the below php file from my javascript file in aws lambda

This is just from w3..

```
<?php
$servername = "arn of database";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM testtable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"] . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

I couldn't get this to work as I now understand you can't make an ajax call unless the code is running on a server

This had lead me onto node and trying the below code, but im not sure if its even possible to run this on aws lambda?

```
var http = require('http');

var answer = "";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');


    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : '',
      user     : '',
      password : '',
      database : ''
    });

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM testtable', function (error, 
results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      answer = results;
    });

}).listen(8080);

"use strict";

var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");

var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.response.speak("HIC launched. Would you like me to list all 
machines?").listen();
    this.emit(':responseReady');
  },

  'ListIntent': function () {
    // var name = this.event.request.intent.slots.answer.value;
    this.response.speak(ListPlant());
    this.emit(':responseReady');
  }
}

var ListPlant = function() {
  return answer;
};



exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

The above is the result of me taking a working lambda function (from where use strict starts) and pasting above it some node that queries the database, saves it in a variable called answer and then just speaks that back.

ATM i'm just testing the connection etc so asking alexa to speak back answer, in the future there will be more to the listPlant function

Is this the right track to take?

Or does it need to be in separate files?

Is it the case i need to add the arn to the skill endpoint?

Can i even run node like this in aws? If not which approach should i take?

I'm determined to get this so even just posting a link with some info would be greatly appreciated

What i've found so far uses python, which isn;t a problem, its making the ajax call from lambda

Thanks in advance! x

Comment: your question doesn't show what you have tried so far. Perhaps you could post what you are trying to do in PHP and some of your lambda code to help others answer your question. It would also help to know which RDS you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa will call a Lambda function. That Lambda function can then access your Amazon RDS database.

It is not easy to write an Alexa function in PHP. The best-supported languages are **Node.js/JavaScript** and **Python**.

I suggest you start by **experimenting with basic Alexa skills** so that you understand the interaction model and how to code a skill, then expand the functionality to provide your specific functionality. (But not in PHP.)